# destroy and spawn various objects after certain time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to destroy and respawn them again on old position after a certain time by tag

problems:

- clones not destroyed
- objects dont spawn on the same place as before
- only spawn one after destroy various

```
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject barrel;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    public int lifetime = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        var obj = GameObject.Find("barrel");
        
        position = obj.transform.position;
        rotation = obj.transform.rotation;
        
        StartCoroutine(Spawn(lifetime));
    }

    private IEnumerator Spawn(int secs)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(secs);
        
        foreach (var b in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("barrel"))
        {
            Destroy(b);
            Debug.Log("barrel destroyed");
        }
        Instantiate(barrel, position, rotation);
        Debug.Log("barrel spawned");
    }
```

[repository](https://github.com/fgsoftware1/survival)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what it is you're trying to achieve in your Update function, because you're setting your rotation and position to the `obj` barrel which I'm pretty sure is just going to be the first barrel in the hierarchy every time, so you're spawning barrels on top of each other constantly

Comment: @A-Fairooz im destroing and spawning on same position(not working)

Comment: @A-Fairooz i see im passing position on Update() and rotation what shlould be on Start() method. now barrel spawning on the same position but still spawning one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy and respawn on the same position with a delay, you should use the built in delay on the `Destroy` function in combination with `InvokeRepeating` like so, but I would recommend changing the lifetime to something higher than 0:

```
[SerializeField]
    private GameObject barrel;
    private Vector3 position;
    private Quaternion rotation;
    public int lifetime = 1;
    private void Start()
    {
        var obj = GameObject.Find("barrel");
        position = obj.transform.position;
        rotation = obj.transform.rotation;
        //InvokeRepeating(string MethodName, float StartDelay, float RepeatRate)
        //This runs the Spawn(); function every 'lifetime' seconds with 0 delay at the start
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 0, lifetime);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
    //No need to run the coroutine every frame
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
        var bar = Instantiate(barrel, position, rotation); //Spawn the barrel but keep a reference to it
        Destroy(bar, lifetime); //Destroy the barrel after 'lifetime' seconds
    }
```

Comment: not working after lifetime barrel is not destroyed

Comment: If you haven't changed any of the values then a new barrel is spawning as soon as the old one is destroyed, to fix that change `InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 0, lifetime);` to `InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 0, lifetime + 2);`

Comment: i set lifetime to 5

Comment: @GabrielAguiar The important part is that the invocation repeat rate is greater than the delay on the destroy, eg: `InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 0, 7);` - This spawns a new barrel every 7 seconds, `Destroy(bar, 5);` - This destroys the spawned barrel every 5 seconds, this way you don't have barrels overlapping eachother

Comment: after 5 seconds barrel not destroyed and after 7 seconds barrel(clone) spawned overlapped(still spawning only one) i wanted to spawn one for each destroyed